# xml<-->json converter which preserves types

Tags: xml, json, json.net, converters

I need an xml<-->json converter which preserves types.
For example:

**json**:

```
"number": 1
```

**to xml**:

```
<number>1</number>
```

**back to json**:

```
"number": 1
```

the converters I've found so far will return back to json like this:

```
"number": "1"
```

(a string semantics and not int)

Of course I understand the semantics is lost in the translation. I wonder if any converter tried to preserve the type on the xml like this:

```
<number xsi:type="s:int">1</number>
```

or to use xml schema etc.

Comment: What Xml serializer have you tried? What version of .Net are you using (how is the type information represented after deserialization from JSON - dynamic types?)

Comment: I use .Net 4. I don't do deserialization, I need to pass the json to the other system as is.

Comment: OK, understood - I didn't even realize json.Net had built-in Xml conversion functionality; have you tried deserializing the Json to a dynamic object, serializing that dynamic object using another Xml seralizer (eg http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html), and then back? The xml would likely be ugly as hell (not sure how XmlSerializer handles Dynamic), but I'm not sure what your Xml-format requirements are...

Comment: the xml needs to be readable, e.g. in the example I gave

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head when you said they're semantically different. If you want the sort of xml you're after (and presumably you have a small domain of types you're expecting?) then I doubt there's a generalised tool that will do it. Have you seen (machine written) SOAP messages?

Comment: it's not a small domain unfortunately, this needs to be generic. Not sure how SOAP s helpful here.